# Как передать парамет из функции в другую функцию?

Tags: javascript

Хочу показать на простом примере:

первая функция:

```js
const sayHi() {
  const hi = 'Hi';
  say();
}
```

вторая функция:

```js
const say = () => {
  console.log(hi); 
// как сюда передать значение переменной hi из соседней функции?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя получить значение локальной переменной из соседней функции.

Что бы передать параметр, его нужно, эээ, передать. Например так:

```js
const sayHi = () => {
  const hi = 'Hi';
  say(hi);
};

const say = (str) => {
  console.log(str);
};
```

Comment: Как hi передается из sayHi в console.log? И что значит аргумент str?

Comment: @AndreyVolkov, вот так: `say(hi);`

Comment: @AndreyVolkov Начните с букваря https://learn.javascript.ru/
Конкретно про функции https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics

Comment: hi и str в данном случае это одна и таже переменная. просто при передаче переменной в функцию мы указываем уже существующую переменную (hi) а во второй функции мы указываем имя новой переменной и приравниваем ее к той которую передали. Таким же способом мы могли бы передать в функцию сразу строку ``say("Hi")``

Answer (score 2):

Для передачи переменной во вторую функцию нужно использовать подобную конструкцию:

```js
const sayHi = () => {
    const hi = "HI";
    say(hi) // Передаем объявленную переменную из первой функции во вторую
}

const say = (hi) => {
    console.log(hi)
}


sayHi();
```

`const hi = "HI";` будет видима только для функции в которой вы ее объявили.

Для того чтобы переменную сделать видимой для всех функций в файле нужно ее объявить глобально для этого файла. Вот так:

```js
const hi = "HI";

const sayHi = () => {
    say(hi) // Функция видит переменную которая в ней не объявлена
}

const say = (hi) => {
    console.log(hi)
}


sayHi();
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнении к предыдущему ответу. Вы можете задать глобальную переменную var hi = 'Hi'; Проверить, что переменная является глобальной можно через window.hi; Но уровень "чистоты" данного решения, зависит от задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, давайте подумаем:

1. Элевация кода / модификация функции (см. `.toString()` -> парсим тело функции, добавляем переменную, элевация и вот названная локальная переменная в рамках иной функции; можно, кстати, прям там и объявить эту функцию, либо `.toString()`);
2. Глобальные переменные (window.myvar) или же даже ([window|process].mysecurenamespace.myvar); никто не мешает сделать вспомогательную обработку mysecurenamespace вида `` for (var _Tvar of window.mysecurenamespace) {eval(`var ${_Tvar}=window.mysecurenamespace.${_Tvar};`)} ``; однако, любителям констант<-чисто гуманитарная штука (+ весят в памяти + delete в 'use strict' отдельная тема) не подходит.
3. `` var _Tarr=[];for (var _Tvar in Array.from(arguments) {_Tarr.push(`arguments[${_Tvar}]`)}; eval(`myAnotherFunc(${_Tarr.join(',')})`) ``

Comment: Никто не мешает сделать что-то в стиле ```window[my very secure namespace that isn't access with window.mynamespace <- use non-variable-valid naming of namespace with -`${[require('node:crypto')|window.crypto]}` для рандомайзера]```. В общем, удачи в этом, непростом(?), деле.

Я вот лениво делаю http://npmjs.com/package/typexts и вскоре добавлю туда `typexts.function.fun`, где будет метод `.inject` как иллюстрация, т.к. в любом случае наглядно и идея не в том, чтобы популяризировать (как де-факто бывает) засорение `node_modules`, а в том, что там есть `code` вкладка на странице.

Comment: Кстати, рецепт от пользователей `const`:

```;(function(_Tvar){
//_Tvar здесь защищена;
});```

можно делать обработки с временными переменными так + нормальное наименование опций в function() сделает читабельнее и логичнее код + /**/ комментарии и в итоге код явствует; я просто пишу обычно тот код, который поддерживает элевацию или её распознаёт (что влияет на поведение), а потому мне де-факто привычно такое, думаю, что и Вам такой рецепт полезен, т.к., лучше хотя бы на правах сниппетов делать вот такие вещи, чтобы их особо не редактироовать